# Chrome Extension "Script-src" error (self-learning)

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

I am self-learning JavaScript after learning C++ in school, and I thought it would be good practice to try to build a Chrome Extension. I am trying to access OpenWeatherMap's API to get the city ID to do a weather search.

Here is the part of the code that is causing the problem:

```
var cityParam = $('#cityInput').val(); //ex. of cityParam = "New York"
        var cityURL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?callback=?&q="+ cityParam + "&type=like&sort=population&cnt=30";

        var cityJSON;

        $.getJSON(cityURL, function(data) {
            cityJSON = data;
}
```

The error I received from Chrome was:

```
Refused to load the script [url] ... because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:".
```

I did a Google search and it seems like Chrome Extensions are very strict in what you can and cannot do (ex: cannot inline javascript). Not being very familiar with web development, I'm not quite sure where to start looking on how to solve this problem.

The URL returns (I believe) a JSON, but it starts with an extra **?(** and ends with a **)**.

Thanks for the help!

**Edit:**
Here is a screenshot of the error I took. It appears the red highlighted text is from jQuery. Perhaps the URL I am passing in cannot be processed by $.getJSON()?
[image]

**Edit 2:**
I added the following to my manifest as suggested by *meda*, but the error still persists:

```
"permissions": [
    "http://api.openweathermap.org/*" 
 ]
```

Comment: This might help also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25867584/extension-refuses-to-load-the-script-due-to-content-security-policy-directive

Comment: if your target endpoint supports https, then simply add this line at `manifest.json`: `"content_security_policy":"script-src 'self' https://example.com; object-src 'self'"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL includes `callback=?` this is a common pattern for [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) where APIs that support it will wrap JSON in a simple JavaScript function. The response data gets handed to the JS function and avoids browser XHR restrictions. Simply remove `callback=?` from the API URL and you should be fine.

Comment: thats unrelated to his issue and thus not a valid answer.

Comment: @ZigMandel nope. `Refused to load the script` is caused because `callback=?` tells the server to return JavaScript instead of JSON.

Comment: no. see the other answer and reason to close as dup thou yours seems like a 2nd error. hes asking why it refuses to load thou.

Comment: @ZigMandel if you look at the answer of the Q this was marked as dup for, it says the same thing my answer does. `$.getJSON('URL which does NOT contain callback=?', ...);`

Comment: grr can't upvote you unless you make an edit (says s.o.) add a space or something

Answer (score -1):

It's not the JSON that is invalid, it's a restriction of chrome apps for security purposes.

You will need to give your app permission to load an external `url`.

This is done in the manifest file

```
"permissions": [
    "http://api.openweathermap.org/*" 
]
```

Comment: Thanks! I still seem to get the _Refused to load the script_ error after adding the URL in the manifest file. The red underlined text appears to be in jQuery. I have updated the first post to show the screenshot I took.

Comment: Same for me. Adding this to `manifest.json` didn't help.

Comment: I can confirm, just adding this does not resolve loading js from a external url.