# Injecting AJAX into website via Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I am using a chrome extension to inject an AJAX request into a website. However I keep randomly getting this error:

> Refused to connect to 'http://127.0.0.1:5005/' because it violates the
>   following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self'
>   static.licdn.com media.licdn.com static-exp1.licdn.com
>   static-exp2.licdn.com media-exp1.licdn.com media-exp2.licdn.com
>   https://media-src.linkedin.com/media/ www.linkedin.com
>   s.c.lnkd.licdn.com m.c.lnkd.licdn.com s.c.exp1.licdn.com
>   s.c.exp2.licdn.com m.c.exp1.licdn.com m.c.exp2.licdn.com
>   wss://*.linkedin.com dms.licdn.com".

It doesn't happen all the time. Just some of the time. I am really confused. Is there a way around it?

This is the code inside `chrome_extension.js`

```
function checkName(){
    var fullNameSplit = $('#topcard h1').first().text().split(' ');
    var firstName = fullNameSplit[0]
    var lastName = fullNameSplit[fullNameSplit.length - 1]
    console.log(firstName, lastName)
    console.log('checking name')

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'http://127.0.0.1:5005/',
        data: JSON.stringify({first: firstName, last: lastName}),
        success: function(response) {
            data = JSON.parse(response)
            firstNameFound = data.first_name
            lastNameFound = data.last_name
            fullNameFound = data.full_name
            $('.profile-info').prepend('Full Name Found: '+fullNameFound+'</br></br>');
            //</br></br>First Name Found: '+firstNameFound+'</br></br>Last Name Found: '+lastNameFound+'</br></br>'

        },
        // dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json"
    })
}
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Upstart Extension",
    "version": "1.0",

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icons/download.png"
        // "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "background": {
        "scripts" : ["background.js"]
    },

    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "https://ajax.googleapis.com/",
        "storage"
    ],

    "content_scripts": [
       {
            // "matches":["https://www.linkedin.com/*"],
            "matches": ["https://www.linkedin.com/*", "http://www.linkedin.com/*"],
            "js":["keypress.js", "jquery.js", "chrome_extension.js"],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' http://127.0.0.1:5005/'; connect-src 'self' http://127.0.0.1:5005/'; object-src 'self'"
}
```

Comment: No, there's no way around it as that is the [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) and it's purpose is to prevent what you're trying to do.

Comment: Then why does it work some of the time?

Comment: Does it work sometimes on that same page? There is most likely a different CSP when it succeeds. Look at the page HTML and the headers sent from the server when loading the page in the developer tools, do you see the security policy?

Comment: It sometimes works on the page, sometimes it doesn't. I assume its just Linkedin not adding the security policy on all pages.

Comment: That's what I'd assume as well. I looked at the network requests and it looks like the CSP is a header on the first GET request to `www.linkedin.com`. Here's a [screenshot of the header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90hHr.png) -- that's what I'd look for on other pages to see if it exists / what the differences are.

Comment: Have you tried putting the XHR call in a script, and then adding that script into your Chrome extensions manifest.json, rather than injecting the XHR directly into the page? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34950159/1526037) answer for a sample.

Comment: And here's the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy) for CSP within the context of Chrome extensions. It looks to me like it should be possible to make a request in a script.

Comment: @SinanBolel I added the code. Can you take a look? I'm still getting the error

Comment: Your security policy has `https://example.com` in it -- change that to the address you're trying to hit (127.0.0.1). Also, change `script-src` to `connect-src` --- Try this: `"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://127.0.0.1; "connect-src 'self' https://127.0.0.1; object-src 'self'"`

Comment: Hmm...I tried some variations. Changed `https` to `http` and tried it with/without `:5005` but still getting the error. Any thoughts?

Comment: updated the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169602/discussion-between-sinan-bolel-and-morgan-allen).

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you're being blocked by a websites [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) which is a security policy set by the webserver which provides a list of servers it is allowed to connect to. Basically, it's a piece of security designed to stop exactly what you're doing because it looks like an XSS injection attack.

It likely only happens some of the time because only some sites have CSP enabled.

`Is there a way around it?`

Assuming CSP is effective, no there isn't a way around it unless the site in question adds the source you're connecting to to it's content policy.