# Using 'script-src' to allow websites isn't affecting error

Tags: html, content-security-policy

I'm making a browser extension but the Content Security Policy seems to be blocking some of my content. I've added a `meta` tag to allow for a website:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://cdn.jsdelivr.net">
```

I'm still getting the same error message saying that the script-src is being blocked.

[image: Warning that Loading failed for the script with source...]

[image: Error that the Content Security Policy settings blocked the resource from loading]

**How do I allow my resource to load?**

p.s. I'm targeting Firefox and Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I needed to put the code in my `manifest.json` file, instead of in the `<head>` of my `html` file. It should look something like this:

```json
}
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://cdn.jsdelivr.net; object-src 'self'",
}
```

I was able to find an answer in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34950009/chrome-extension-refused-to-load-the-script-because-it-violates-the-following-c?rq=1) to help me with this.