# Violating Content Security Policy directive on Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, youtube-api, google-api-js-client

We are trying to load the script src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js' into our Chrome extension in order to access `gapi` (Google API). However, whenever we have `<script src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js'></script>` in our html file, we repeatedly get this error:

`Refused to load the script 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem:". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback."`

We have tried several of the solutions from [this StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34950009/chrome-extension-refused-to-load-the-script-because-it-violates-the-following-c), however none of them seemed to work. We are just trying to access the `gapi` library in order to search for YouTube videos.

EDIT: Here is our mainfest.json. "https://apis.google.com/js/" includes gapi that we are trying to include.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Extension",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Extension description",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
        "16": "images/icon16.png",
        "24": "images/icon24.png",
        "32": "images/icon32.png"
    }
  },
    "content_scripts": [{
      "js": ["popup.js"],
      "matches": ["https://apis.google.com/js/"]
    }]
}
```

Any ideas on why this is? Thank you for the help!

Comment: Show your manifest.json, specifically `content_security_policy`. Also make sure you've reloaded the extension on chrome://extensions page after editing manifest.json.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you for your response! We have added the manifest.json above.

Comment: You have a violation message `...because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem:"`, it means your app uses non-default CSP. But I do not see [`content_security_policy` key](http://csplite.com/csp268/#default_CSP) in your web manifest. Is it your full web manifest?