# Chrome extension Manifest V3 Issue : Trying google login in the extension built with react.js showing following error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

[image: this is the error i am getting when i click on google signin button]
It is working perfectly fine in localhost:3000. Tried every possible solution present in the web but stuck in it around 3 days.I am expecting an approach or solution that can work.Thanks!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome Extension "Refused to load the script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34950009/chrome-extension-refused-to-load-the-script-because-it-violates-the-following-c)

Comment: No, it did not solve the problem.