# Replacing $ .ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I was called to update a website and I'm having trouble implementing a JS code, not having to expose customer codes, created a replica of the problem.

The first code is located at: http://habbxo.esy.es/index.html that has the tag

```
<script src = 'https: //code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js' 
type ='text/javascript'> </ script>
```

and the code works perfectly.

However in http://habbxo.esy.es/index2.html which removed the  tag the code is not running, is the problem I'm having, as the client server when I call the script Jquery me is returned:

> Refused to load the script 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js because it violates The Following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'

How to solve this?

Comment: There are many tutorials on how to use AJAX with plain Javascript. Or change the site's Content Security Policy.

Comment: How can I convert this code into pure? `$.ajax({
  url: "http://habbxo.esy.es/test.html",
  success: function b64EncodeUnicode(entry) {
    nome = entry.split("uniqueId\":\"")[1]["split"]("\"")[0];
  }
});


        setTimeout(function(){alert(nome)},1000);`

Comment: That is a horrible filter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use pure **Javascript** instead of **Jquery** Ajax function, try:

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.addEventListener("load", function(e){
            var entry = e.target.responseText;
            nome = entry.split("mynameIs\":\"")[1]["split"]("\"")[0];
            setTimeout(function(){alert(nome)},1000);
        }, false);
        ajax.open("POST", "http://habbxo.esy.es/test.txt");
        ajax.send();
```

Back to the original problem, that error seems to be a chrome's extension "Content Security Policy" restriction, you can check this problem and the solution here [Extension refuses to load the script due to Content Security Policy directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25867584/extension-refuses-to-load-the-script-due-to-content-security-policy-directive)