# Get data from json file and display the value using jquery/ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, google-chrome-extension

The following function should display an alert message with the value it gets from the JSON file.

```
function ajaxTest() {
    let currencyRate = "";

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/convert?q=USD_INR&compact=y",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(json) {
            let myObject = JSON.parse(json);
            currencyRate += myObject.USD_INR.val;
        }
    })

    alert(currencyRate);
}
```

The json file looks like the following.

```
{"USD_INR":{"val":72.037972}}
```

The code isn't working. It's showing a blank alert box so the ajax portion isn't correct.

Comment: Tried console logging your response?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: yeah, console.log came out blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a async function call, you need to put alert in your ajax success function

```
function ajaxTest() {
    let currencyRate = "";

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/convert?q=USD_INR&compact=y",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(json) {
            let myObject = JSON.parse(json);
            currencyRate += myObject.USD_INR.val;

            // put alert here
            alert(currencyRate);
        }
    })
}
```

Or a better approach would be like below.

```
ajaxTest().then(function( json ) {
   let myObject = JSON.parse(json);
   currencyRate += myObject.USD_INR.val;

   // put alert here
   alert(currencyRate);
});
```

Or even use callbacks as follows:

```
function ajaxTest( callback ) {
        let currencyRate = "";

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/convert?q=USD_INR&compact=y",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function(json) {
                let myObject = JSON.parse(json);
                currencyRate += myObject.USD_INR.val;


                callback(currencyRate);
            }
        })
    }

ajaxTest(function( result ) {
  alert(result)
})
```

## Updated

No need to parse the return json at all.

```
function ajaxTest() {
    let currencyRate = "";

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/convert?q=USD_INR&compact=y",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(json) {
            // no need to parse it to json anymore
            // let myObject = JSON.parse(json);
            currencyRate += json.USD_INR.val;

            // put alert here
            alert(currencyRate);
        }
    })
}

ajaxTest();
```

The above code should work, since the return json itself is a json and no need to parse it to json anymore.

Comment: still not working for me. no alert box showing up. can I call the function as usual like ajaxTest();

Comment: make sure that your ajax request does not have any error, and return the expected json. Actually make sure that your ajax success callback will run.

Comment: @NoobCoder Try the updated one, the problem is with trying to parse it to json.

Comment: still not seeing any alert boxes

Comment: Do you call the `ajaxTest` function?

Comment: I did call it. I'm seeing some errors as follows: https://i.postimg.cc/hjrfwmPz/000668.jpg

Comment: @NoobCoder Your problem is not with the code you have posted in your question, it is a chrome extension issue. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25867584/extension-refuses-to-load-the-script-due-to-content-security-policy-directive

Comment: Thanks sadrzadehsina. now it's working after I added the content_security_policy

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with your current code

1. The `dataType` should be `json` instead of `jsonp`.
2. There's no need
   to re-parse the success response (json) as jQuery ajax handles it for you all you need to do is to just iterate over it.

So Your current code will be as follows

```js
function ajaxTest() {
  let currencyRate = "";

  $.ajax({
    url: "http://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/convert?q=USD_INR&compact=y",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
      currencyRate += json.USD_INR.val;
      console.log(currencyRate)
      alert(currencyRate);
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onClick="ajaxTest()">Get Rates</button>
```